# Recursive CTE or While Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to pivot into rows the columns VNLAMNT, MXBAMNT, HZLAMNT, DARKAMNT, STWBRYAMNT in the Orders table and append the value Description in ChocolateType table to each row in the most efficient manner possible.

The table schemas are like so:

**ChocolateTypes**

```
Id | Description
```

**Orders**

```
CUSTOMERCLASS | OFFICE | LOCATION | VNLAMNT | MXBAMNT | HZLAMNT | DARKAMNT | STWBRYAMNT
```

I want the result set to look like this with 15 records (3 descriptions * 5 columns), as per values in tables in Fiddle:

**Result**

```
CUSTOMERCLASS | OFFICE | LOCATION | VALUE | TYPE 
Proprietary Head    Chicago 2 Vanilla
Proprietary Head    Chicago 14 MixedBerry
Proprietary Head    Chicago 14 Hazelnut
Proprietary Head    Chicago 14 Dark
Proprietary Head    Chicago 14 Strawberry
```

I have the tables in Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10f89/1/0

VALUE is populated with the value in each of the columns VNLAMNT, MXBAMNT, HZLAMNT, DARKAMNT, STWBRYAMNT. The sequence is always as above. TYPE is populated with Description from the ChocolateTypes table.

I have looked at recursive CTE's and it appears these are not the most efficient way of looping through the records but I am unsure of how to do it either with CTE's or with a While Loop. 
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It would be great if you showed what you want as the desired result with the data instead of just column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for recursive CTE nor while loop simply an UPIVOT query will do the trick, see below.....

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT  ORDERID
           ,CUSTOMERCLASS
           ,OFFICE
           ,LOCATION
           ,VALUE
           ,CASE [TYPE]
             WHEN 'MXBAMNT'    THEN 1
             WHEN 'VNLAMNT'    THEN 2
             WHEN 'HZLAMNT'    THEN 3
             WHEN 'STWBRYAMNT' THEN 4
             WHEN 'DARKAMNT'   THEN 5
            END AS [TYPE]
    FROM dbo.Orders
    UNPIVOT ( VALUE FOR [TYPE]
              IN (VNLAMNT, MXBAMNT, HZLAMNT, DARKAMNT, STWBRYAMNT)
            )up
   )
SELECT  C.ORDERID
       ,C.CUSTOMERCLASS
       ,C.OFFICE
       ,C.LOCATION
       ,C.VALUE
       ,CT.[DESCRIPTION]
FROM CTE C INNER JOIN dbo.ChocolateTypes CT
ON C.[TYPE] = CT.ID
```

### [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/caffe/5)

Comment: Hi - this is correct for what I've requested so I'm up voting. The problem I have is a little more complex. The number of records in ChocolateTypes and also Orders is not fixed. Everytime a new record is added to ChocolateType this query would need to be altered, hence the need to use rCTE's or a while loop (I think!).

Comment: but you do have a set number of columns in your `dbo.Orders` table dont you? if you dont and every order adds a new column then you need to pay serious attention to your schema. This table as it is violates basic rules of database normalization. you should have only one column which should store ID or chocolateType in orders table, and multiple rows for each order.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I do have a set number of columns. This is a scaled down version for simplicity, there are 27 columns in the live table I'm working with.

Comment: Also you can add another column in your ChocolateType tables and add values which are column names for each ChocoType in orders table, then you can use the above query without using case statement, and simple join the TYPE column from above query to your new column in ChocolateType table. Not a problem always glad to help.